# Change stroke values on Kendo UI Radial Gauge

Tags: javascript, svg, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm trying to have the Kendo UI Radial Gauge draw some strokes around the radial border itself. I'm able to manipulate the svg file output through the chrome console at runtime, but I'm hoping it's possible to manipulate the source so it comes out like this at default:
[image]

Here's a snippet from the console, where I've added the stroke value at the end of the tag:

```
<path style="display: block; " d="M 21.748 348.065 A230 230 0 1,1 448.252 348.065 L 434.345 342.445 A215 215 0 1,0 35.655 342.445 z" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="white" stroke="#d2d3d6"></path>
```

Was hoping that someone have done this before, seeing as there's no official setting for this that I've been able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Kendo, this is not possible. Ended up using coloring inside the gauge, to at least get *some* kind of effect different than the white background.
[image]